# favicon now showing up

Tags: favicon

I have wordpress installed in the /home directory on my server, so it was set up that you would have to go to www.mywordpress.com/home to see my wordpress and just going to www.mywordpress.com would take you to a different homepage. Well, I went into my setting and change the Site Url so to www.mywordpress.com so that my wordpress would be my homepage. Today, I tried to setup a favicon and it only works if the url is www.mywordpress.com/home/whatever even if you try going to www.mywordpress.com/whatever. If the /home isnt in there the favicon doesn't show up.

I have the code pasted in my header.php template

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have put the code in your header.php is the full URL to the Favicon correct?

Also check in another browser as Favicons can be heavily cached (so check another machine)

I'm assuming the non / page (without home) has the favicon code present on it as well?

What is URL?

Comment: That may be it (putting the entire url to the favicon. I will try that real quick.

Comment: Thank you! That worked :) I didn't think that I had to give the /home url in there. Simple and correct! I appreciate it!

Comment: Good to hear it :-D